# Docker Swarm service simple example does not reply to curl

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, wsl-2

I am trying to deploy a simple docker swarm service using routing mesh from this [manual pages](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/services/#publish-a-services-ports-using-the-routing-mesh) and access it.

Initialize docker swarm cluster with single manager node:

```
PS> docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.1.156

Swarm initialized: current node (jpajl1nkr3xr1f3c3jqi56qia) is now a manager.

To add a worker to this swarm, run the following command:

    docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-2n1s6wap5dp1pjzzzqroyg22pqkwpnfijilmbdfgwjbkcqwder-5kqt701dv329fduhoaqld9m3y 192.168.1.156:2377

To add a manager to this swarm, run 'docker swarm join-token manager' and follow the instructions.
```

Deploy service:

```
PS> docker service create --name my_web --publish published=80,target=80 --replicas 3 nginx

fqy4vi3hjncougtak9qj9fuz0
overall progress: 3 out of 3 tasks
1/3: running   [==================================================>]
2/3: running   [==================================================>]
3/3: running   [==================================================>]
verify: Service converged
```

Check service and containers:

```
PS> docker service ls

ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE               PORTS
fqy4vi3hjnco        my_web              replicated          3/3                 nginx:latest        *:80->80/tcp

PS> docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
d24a85b4d6ba        nginx:latest        "/docker-entrypoint.…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        80/tcp              my_web.2.b44g8bjs95ac8v0g90hnv2cjd
b6466f252b46        nginx:latest        "/docker-entrypoint.…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        80/tcp              my_web.3.hpc4zxlr178tklf84t1y5rc64
35e194264098        nginx:latest        "/docker-entrypoint.…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        80/tcp              my_web.1.u1euqrfwq2te75zsbkmfkv0bq
```

Request:

```
PS> curl http://localhost
curl : Se ha terminado la conexión: La conexión ha terminado de forma inesperada.
<< (Free Translation) curl: Connection is terminated: The connection has finished unexpectedly.  >>

En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ curl http://localhost
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Same result with these alternatives:

```
PS> curl http://localhost:80
PS> curl http://127.0.0.1:80
PS> curl http://192.168.1.156
PS> curl http://192.168.1.156:80
```

Check listening ports in Windows:

```
CMD> netstat -a -b | find "80"

  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             fs1322:0               LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7680           fs1322:0               LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           fs1322:0               LISTENING
  TCP    169.254.80.254:139     fs1322:0               LISTENING
  TCP    172.19.80.1:53         fs1322:0               LISTENING
  TCP    172.19.80.1:139        fs1322:0               LISTENING
```

Check listening ports in one container

```
# netstat -ltpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:34835        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/nginx: master pro
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1/nginx: master pro
```

The execution of `curl localhost` in one container succeded:

```
# curl localhost
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
...
</head>
</html>
```

Environment:

- OS: Windows 10 Pro (2004)
- Docker Desktop for Windows: 2.3.0.3
- Docker Engine: 19.03.8
- Virtualization: WSL2
- Console: Windows PowerShell (not Administrator)

Comment: I tried same steps with a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 Server installation and found the same problem.

Comment: try out `curl http://127.0.0.1:80`

Comment: Not working with `curl http://127.0.0.1:80`